# LINQ To SQL - Select a constant value

Tags: linq-to-sql

In SQL you can selecta constant value:

```
Select "Constant Text", Column1, Column2 From TableX
```

and each row returned from TableX starts with a column containing the text "Constant Text".
Any ideas on how I can do this in LINQ to SQL?
If I do the above I get the error message "Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, each property in the resulting anonymous class needs a name, so in the following code, we are naming the constant column `ConstantColumn`. The 2nd and 3rd properties will by default take the names of the queried columns, so they will be named `Column1` and `Column2` respectively:

```
var query = from x in db.TableX
            select new
            {
                ConstantColumn = "Constant Text",
                x.Column1,
                x.Column2
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

from tx in dc.TableX
select new { "constant text", tx.Column1, tx.Column2 };

Answer (score 1):

```
var db = new DataContext();

var query = from x in db.TableX
            select new {"Constant Text", x.Column1, x.Column2};
```

..i think it's something like that.